# custom workflow with with email sent on field edit

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a custom workflow used for issue tracking and I want to have an email sent each time a field changes. I can get it work on the first field change but there are no emails sent on subsequent changes. Is there any way to do this with Sharepoint Designer?

Comment: Ok after working on this all day I just kind of found an answer. I created a second workflow with only one step. This workflow is simply "Email CurrentItem:CreatedBy". I have this workflow set to run every time an item is changed. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the original workflow run on every item change as well, and just have a guaranteed step of sending an email at the end.